# How to start new activity from button in alert dialog?

Tags: java, android

In this app, I created scanner and the result will shown in `alertDialog`with two button; `OK` and `NEXT.NEXT` button I would like to go to new activity.The problem is, when click the NEXT button, it crash.

please help me..
i'm new.

```
  @Override
    public void handleResult(final Result result) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(qrscanner.this);
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("NEXT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(qrscanner.this,attend_form.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

this attend_form

```
public class attend_form extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
Button btn_get_sign, mClear, mGetSign, mCancel, btn_rega;
RadioGroup battend;

EditText File,Ic;
String file_number,ic_no;
String attendance = "";
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
String url_reg = "http://192.168.1.7/spm/android/attendance/attend.php";

File file;
Dialog dialog;
LinearLayout mContent;
View view;
signature mSignature;
Bitmap bitmap;

// Creating Separate Directory for saving Generated Images
String DIRECTORY = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DigitSign/";
String pic_name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
String StoredPath = DIRECTORY + pic_name + ".png";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attend_form);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // Setting ToolBar as ActionBar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    btn_rega = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_rega);

    final RadioGroup battend = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.attendance);
    final RadioButton attend = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_attend);
    final RadioButton absent = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_absent);

    // Button to open signature panel
    btn_get_sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signature);

    File = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.file_number);
    Ic = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ic_no);

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(attend_form.this);


    btn_rega.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            file_number = File.getText().toString();
            ic_no = Ic.getText().toString();
            if (battend.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == attend.getId())
            {
                attendance = "ATTEND";
            }

            else if(battend.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == absent.getId())
            {
                attendance = "ABSENT";
            }



            if(file_number.equals("") || ic_no.equals(""))
            {
                builder.setTitle("Something were wrong");
                builder.setMessage("Please fill all field");
                displayAlert("input_error");
            }

            else
            {

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_reg, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                            String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                            builder.setTitle("Server Response");
                            builder.setMessage(message);
                            displayAlert(code);
                        }catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getPostParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("file_number",file_number);
                        params.put("ic_no",ic_no);
                        params.put("attendance",attendance);
                        return super.getPostParams();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("file_number",file_number);
                        params.put("ic_no",ic_no);
                        params.put("attendance",attendance);
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                MySingleton.getInstance(attend_form.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);

            }

        }
    });



    // Method to create Directory, if the Directory doesn't exists
    file = new File(DIRECTORY);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }

    // Dialog Function
    dialog = new Dialog(attend_form.this);
    // Removing the features of Normal Dialogs
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_signature);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);



    btn_get_sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Function call for Digital Signature
            dialog_action();

        }
    });

}

public void displayAlert(final String code)
{
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {

            if(code.equals("input_error"))
            {
                File.setText("");
                Ic.setText("");

            }
            else if(code.equals("reg_success"))
            {
                finish();

            }
            else if(code.equals("reg_failed"))
            {
                File.setText("");
                Ic.setText("");
            }

        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}



// Function for Digital Signature
public void dialog_action() {

    mContent = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    mSignature = new signature(getApplicationContext(), null);
    mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    // Dynamically generating Layout through java code
    mContent.addView(mSignature, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mClear = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.clear);
    mGetSign = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.getsign);
    mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
    mCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    view = mContent;

    mClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Cleared");
            mSignature.clear();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mSignature.save(view, StoredPath);
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Calling the same class
            recreate();

        }
    });

    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");
            dialog.dismiss();
            // Calling the same class
            recreate();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}



public class signature extends View {

    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
    private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    private float lastTouchX;
    private float lastTouchY;
    private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    public void save(View v, String StoredPath) {
        Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
        Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        try {
            // Output the file
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(StoredPath);
            v.draw(canvas);

            // Convert the output file to Image such as .png
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
        }

    }

    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                lastTouchX = eventX;
                lastTouchY = eventY;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                    float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                    float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                    expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                    path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                }
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;

            default:
                debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                return false;
        }

        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    private void debug(String string) {

        Log.v("log_tag", string);

    }

    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
            dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
            dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }

        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
            dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
            dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}
}
```

StringRequestClass

```
public class StringRequestClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    //Your task happens here

    EditText File,Ic;
    String file_number,ic_no;
    String attendance = "";
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    String url_reg = "http://192.168.1.7/spm/android/attendance/attend.php";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do your StringRequest here.





        if(file_number.equals("") || ic_no.equals(""))
        {
            builder.setTitle("Something were wrong");
            builder.setMessage("Please fill all field");
            displayAlert("input_error");
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Things to do when your task is complete.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Do everything you want to do after the StringRequest is completed.

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_reg, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                    String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                    builder.setTitle("Server Response");
                    builder.setMessage(message);
                    displayAlert(code);
                }catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){


            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("file_number",file_number);
                params.put("ic_no",ic_no);
                params.put("attendance",attendance);
                return params;
            }
        };

        MySingleton.getInstance(attend_form.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        if(file_number.equals("") || ic_no.equals(""))
        {
            builder.setTitle("Something were wrong");
            builder.setMessage("Please fill all field");
            displayAlert("input_error");
        }
    } //Things to do before the internet-related task

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}


    public void displayAlert(final String code)
    {
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {

                if(code.equals("input_error"))
                {
                    File.setText("");
                    Ic.setText("");

                }
                else if(code.equals("reg_success"))
                {
                    finish();

                }
                else if(code.equals("reg_failed"))
                {
                    File.setText("");
                    Ic.setText("");
                }

            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: post your error log here....

Comment: post attend_form.class code

Comment: Verify if you declared "attend_form" activity on AndroidManifest.xml file or not.

Comment: i already try that code..but still same..
attend_form already added in AndroidManifest.xml
i'm really sorry. I cannot post my error log because i cannot test my app in Android Studio..

Comment: how are you changing the code if not in some IDE? how do you witness the crash? If on your phone, just connect it to your computer and get the log through the adb.

Comment: I think it is because you don't have the proper context. I suggest to use interface to interact with activity then use intent when interface method fires.

Comment: Check my answer, it should solve it.

Comment: hey i guess it was the issue with the orientation setting i guess .. please make sure you call the setRequestedOrientation() before setContentView() @NURAISAHIDA

Comment: I modified my answer again ... please do try that one and tell me if really works or not... @NURAISAHIDA

Comment: @PaulPJoby i ry your answer,but still same..

Comment: thank you Paul, Gaurav..the problem was the drawing..

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `getContext()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), attend_form.class);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with context problems